# jQuery Mobile not starting when used with PhoneGap Cordova 1.9.0 and Windows Phone 7.1.1

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone

I have been unable to get jQuery Mobile to initialize and startup properly when used with PhoneGap Cordova 1.9.0 and Windows Phone 7.1.1 in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on a Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit machine.

Does anybody have a starter project template with a test page that demonstrates how to set up the project correctly?

Comment: Did you get Cordova running without JQM?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this applies to windows phone, but it helps with iOS and Android:

1) Turn off the "automatic page initialization" as explained here:  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

2) In the phonegap "deviceinit" handler for your app, call $.mobile.initializePage();

The problem stems from the fact that jquerymobile rearranges the DOM in many ways and you don't want this to happen until your phone gap application is ready. This happens after the DOM is ready.

In my page, I use this *immediately before* loading jquery mobile:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //this must come before jquery is loaded
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        "use strict";
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
    </script>
```

At the end of the same page I use this to do the final initialization:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //called on phone when device is full initialized
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() {
        "use strict";
        //phone init code that manipulates the DOM...
        $.mobile.initializePage();

    });


    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Tried it but did not work. Getting only grey circle on white screen if that's a helpful clue for anybody. Please note that my app - an HTML5/CSS/jQueryMobile/PhoneGap app - does work just fine on Google Android emulator and on Apple iPhone simulator.  So I am having this problem only on Windows Phone 7.1.1 in Visual Studio 2010 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own template by downloading the Cordova 2.2.0 release and unzip it. Inside the folders there is a sub-folder called incubator-cordova-wp7.zip

Unzip that file and you will see a Visual Studio solution for a sample Cordova project - open it. Then in Visual Studio go to File > Export template and use the default settings. Save it wherever you like and now you have your template.

Create a new project with this new template and just press "Run" and you should see the usual Cordova start page in the Windows Phone emulator.

---

*I am having issues getting jquery mobile working in WP7 though. Not everything seems to be working looking at the layout - like not all the CSS is being applied and I am trying to find out how to debug this thing - quite frustrating. I am surprised since the jqm website says that Windows Phone 7 gets Grade A support. I have noticed that some features get turned on/off when a file is loaded from file or a web address e.g. localStorage. For example open a website in IE then type localStorage in the console - it tells you its an object blah blah. Open an html file from your hard drive and type in localStorage and you get nothing.I have tried messing with angularjs and emberjs and they all have issues in the simulator and IE10 so I think WP7 / IE9 / whatever suck! (imho)*